# Git merge no windows ocorre conflito e não fica marcado a linha no arquivo

Tags: windows, git, cmd, powershell

Ao tentar realizar um git merge no Windows em um arquivo que houve modificação na mesma linha, é apresentado a mensagem:

```
warning: Cannot merge binary files: g.txt (HEAD vs. feature3)
Auto-merging g.txt
CONFLICT (content): Merge conflict in g.txt
Automatic merge failed; fix conflicts and then commit the result.
```

Mas ao abrir o arquivo onde ocorre o aviso, não fica marcado com "<<<< HEAD...".

Como fazer para ficar marcado dessa forma "<<<< HEAD..." a linha em que houve o conflito?

Comment: É um arquivo binário? O Git não vai fazer merge.

Comment: É um arquivo de texto, mas poderia ser um arquivo sem extensão nenhuma, a questão é que no linux funciona normalmente, no windows que não aparece com a marcação no local do erro, a minha dúvida é porque não aparece essa marcação.

Comment: Eu nunca tive um problema desses, se isso é configurável, eu nunca precisei configurar!

Answer (score 0):

Embora o Linux entenda que é um arquivo texto, não significa que o Git entenderá da mesma maneira.

A causa deste erro são diversas:

- O arquivo do repositório está com o *encoding* diferente do arquivo alterado.
- O arquivo tem algumas características que fazem com que o Git ache que é um arquivo binário. Isto pode estar ligado com a codificação usada ou mesmo com conteúdo do arquivo. Longas linhas de texto podem fazer com que o Git interprete o arquivo como binário.

Para resolver, você pode adicionar ao seu repositório um arquivo oculto chamado `.gitattributes`:

```
<projeto>/.gitattributes
```

Dentro dele, adicione:

```
g.txt diff
```

Isto fará com que o Git trate o arquivo como um arquivo de texto. Versione este arquivo para compartilhar a solução com os outros usuários do repositório.